Integral of $z^\frac{1}{p}$ over arbitrary contour
Im trying to solve the following problem: 

Let $\gamma : [t_0, t_1] \to \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\} $  be a closed continious curve with $\gamma(t_0) \in \mathbb{R} ^+$. For $k \in \mathbb{N}$ values of $\sqrt[k]{\gamma(t)}, t \in [t_0, t_1]$ are chosen in such manner that $\sqrt[k]{\gamma(t_0)} > 0$ and mapping $t \to  \sqrt[k]{\gamma (t) }  $ is continious. Express $\int\limits_\gamma \sqrt[k]{z} dz$ in terms of $k, \gamma(t_0)$ and the winding number $\nu_\gamma (0) $

Hint in the book: 
This integral should be evaluated using the analytical continuation of the antiderivative


My  attempt: 
In the simplest case $\gamma(t) = e^{i \nu_\gamma(0) t }, t \in [ 0 ,2\pi ] $, it seems I can get the answer : We know that $z^\frac{1}{k}$ is defined as $e^{\frac{1}{k}\log z }$. Using the condition $\sqrt[k]{\gamma(t_0)} >0 $ we have to choose the branch of $\log z $ appropriately, for example $\log  z = \ln |r|  +  i \arg (z), -\pi < \arg(z) < \pi$. The antiderivative of $z^{\frac{1}{k}}$ would be $\frac{k}{k+1} z^{\frac{k+1}{k}}= \frac{k}{k+1} e^{\frac{k+1}{k}}\log (z)$. Every time the circle $\gamma$ "winds" around $0$ it goes through the line $[0, i\infty]$. Thus, in order to remain continious, we need to jump to the "next" branch cut, given by $e^{\frac{k+1}{k} \log (z) + \frac{k+1}{k}2\pi i }$. Thus, after changing branches $\nu_\gamma (0) $ times, we will end up in the end with the antiderivative $e^{\frac{k+1}{k}\log(z) + \frac{k+1}{k} \nu_\gamma(0) 2\pi i }$. The integral over continious curves is defined as the difference of the antiderivative at the start- and endpoint, thus, the integral over the curve will be $[\gamma(t_0)]^{\frac{k+1}{k}} (e^{\frac{k+1}{k} \nu_\gamma(0) 2\pi i} - 1 )$. 

Im not sure about 2 things, namely: 
a) Is my logic (and answer) for this particular case correct ? 
b) If so, how do we generalize this for all curves $\gamma(t)$ ? 
My idea is to somehow show that  $\gamma \cong e^{i \nu_\gamma (0) t }$ in sense of homotopy, however Im not sure if this holds, and even if it does, its not clear that $\sqrt[k]{z}$ is holomorphic in the the region required to say $\int\limits_\gamma \sqrt[k]{z} dz  = \int\limits_{e^{i\nu_{\gamma}(0) t}}\sqrt[k]{z} dz  $
